# Eclipse gives the error of JNI shared library

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse is unable to open, I installed a fresh copy of jre7 and eclipse but it did not work. First it gives the error message "cannot find virtual machine", so I write path of bin in eclipse.ini file. but now it gives the error message "Failed to load the jni shared library C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll".

how can i fix this problem? I have a 64 bit os. The jre and eclipse are also of 64 bit. so what is the problem?